# Does kubernetes use calico plugin support network policy or not when kube-proxy use ipvs mode?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Does kubernetes use calico plugin support network policy or not when kube-proxy use ipvs mode? Kubernetes+calico+kube-proxy(iptables mode) support network policy function.But I do not know whether it takes effect when kube-proxy uses ipvs(nat) mode or not.

Comment: Read this for more info about what type of questions should be asked in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/calico-network-policy/

Comment: Thank you.I know kubernetes+calico+kube-proxy(iptables mode) works.But I do not know whether  it takes effect when kube-proxy uses ipvs(nat) mode or not.

Comment: And i do not have test environment right now.

Comment: Edit the question so I reverse the donwvote.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: Np. Not sure if you have seen this https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/use-ipvs

Comment: I have browsed entire calico website(https://docs.projectcalico.org/).But I can not find the answer.

Comment: Did you manage to find workaround?